# Microsoft authentication

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to use microsoft graph api and I need authorization code for using that.
Redirecting the application to microsoft login site is not possible in my application.

I need to call this and for that I require authProvider:

```
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .buildClient();
```

I am using this for creating authProvider:

```
UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(CLIENT_ID,
            Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite",
                    "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite"),
            USERNAME, PASSWORD, NationalCloud.Global,
            TENANT, CLIENT_SECRET)
```

On using this I get error:

```
  OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_grant', description='AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'e2bfebf6-cc77-49ec-82a3-28756ad377e5' named 'Milpitas Communications'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

Trace ID: a2b91757-4849-4680-a089-001831ef7b00
Correlation ID: ae894060-a2ce-444c-9889-96fd3cdfaea7

I also tried  to use this to create authprovider:

```
AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(CLIENT_ID,
            Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite",
                    "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite"),
            AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REDIRECT_URL, NationalCloud.Global, "common",
            CLIENT_SECRET);
```

To run the above I need authorization code, can anyone please suggest How I can get the code internally in spring boot application, as my application cannot have client input(for auth) on this?

Or alternatively Is there some other way I can use the IGraphServiceClient for creating a calendar event?

Comment: Please look into this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#UsernamePasswordProvider) and then give a try.

Comment: Have your users enabled mfa? Is the user you logged in as an administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite")` with `Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default")` can resolve this issue.

My code for your reference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String USERNAME = "{username}";
    String PASSWORD = "{password}";
    String TENANT = "{tenantID}";
    String CLIENT_ID = "{clientID}";
    String CLIENT_SECRET = "{clientSecret}";

    UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(CLIENT_ID,
            Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
            USERNAME, PASSWORD, NationalCloud.Global,
            TENANT, CLIENT_SECRET);

    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
            .builder()
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .buildClient();

    User user = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();

    System.out.println(user.userPrincipalName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.
The invalid_grant issue is resolved now.
I am getting a new error while posting the event now.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.Request$Builder.tag(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lokhttp3/Request$Builder;
If you have any idea to solve the above issue please suggest.
Thank you.

Comment: @ArpitJoshi Please share your completed code of posting the event.